# CachePut how to get and Id of returned value?

Tags: java, spring, caching

```
@CachePut(value = "dishDTOs", key = "IDOFTHERETURNEDVALUE")
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "dishDTOList", allEntries = true)
public DishResponseDTO createDish(DishCreationDTO dishCreationDTO) {
    int restaurantId = dishCreationDTO.getRestaurantId();
    var restaurant = restaurantRepository.getById(restaurantId);

    var dish = DishMapper.toDish(dishCreationDTO, restaurant);
    return toDishResponseDTO(dishRepository.save(dish));
}
```

Id is assigned by the DB so I need to get it somehow to put as a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned object can be accessed by SpeL with `#result` and you can access object params with a `.` and field name. For example

```
@CachePut(value = "dishDTOs", key = "#result.id)
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "dishDTOList", allEntries = true)
public DishResponseDTO createDish(DishCreationDTO dishCreationDTO) {
    int restaurantId = dishCreationDTO.getRestaurantId();
    var restaurant = restaurantRepository.getById(restaurantId);

    var dish = DishMapper.toDish(dishCreationDTO, restaurant);
    return toDishResponseDTO(dishRepository.save(dish));
}
```

Change `.id` with your DishResponseDTO field name.